# Why does UITextFIeld return optional value in Swift?

Tags: swift, uitextfield, option-type

Im using a `UITextField` to enter numbers but when I enter the first number it ends up printing `nil`. Then when I enter other numbers it prints out the number I inputed but with an `optional` return type. Why does that happen?

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    //convert string into number
    let input = (numberLabel.text! as NSString).integerValue

    //find answer to label when added by 1111
    let answer = input + 1111
    print(answer)

    let numberText = Int(numberField.text!)
    print("This is number text: \(numberText)

    if answer == numberText {
        print("correct")
        //if user gets answer correct
    } else {
        //if user gets answer incorrect
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you get nil?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson When I enter the first number in the textField it shows nil.

Comment: You are probably using the wrong delegate method here, maybe use something like `textFieldDidEndEditing(_:reason:)`

Comment: `print("This is number text: \(numberText)`

Comment: It only happens when I enter the first number

Comment: @xcode22 make sure your textfields are properly connected.

Comment: You have probably deleter a previous outlet. Right click your text field and check if it still there.

Comment: Just checked that everything looks fine with the outlets

Comment: So what object is nil?

Comment: So when I enter any number for the first time the `numberText` prints out nil

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224597/discussion-between-xcode22-and-leo-dabus).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is probably because you're using `shouldChangeCharactersIn` which doesn't indicate the change in the character until the second character.  Ideally you want the user to be notified of the correct answer after they complete the answer and submit it, in which case you want to use something like `textFieldDidEndEditing`:

```swift
class MyVC: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    let textField = UITextField()
    var numberLabel: UILabel {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "100"
        return label
    }
    let button = UIButton()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.addSubview(textField)
        textField.borderStyle = .roundedRect
        textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            textField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200),
            textField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100)
        ])
        textField.delegate = self
        
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.tag = 1
        button.backgroundColor = .black
        button.setTitle("Answer", for: .normal)
        self.view.addSubview(button)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            button.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textField.trailingAnchor),
            button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200),
            button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100)
        ])
        
    }
    
    @objc func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton!) {
        if case let tag = sender.tag, tag == 1 {
            textField.resignFirstResponder()
        }
    }
    
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        //convert string into number
        let input = (numberLabel.text! as NSString).integerValue
        
        //find answer to label when added by 1111
        let answer = input + 1111
                print(answer)
        
        if let numberText = Int(textField.text ?? "0") {
            print("This is number text: \(numberText)")
            
            if answer == numberText {
                //if user gets answer correct
                print("correct")
            } else {
                //if user gets answer incorrect
                print("wrong")
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks using the `textFieldDidEndEditing ` made it work.

Answer (score 0):

`UITextFied` text property will never return `nil`. Its default value is an empty string. What is returning nil is the `Int` string initializer. Regarding text property optionality IMO is intentional to allow you to assign an optional string without the need to unwrap it first.

```
let numberText = Int(textField.text!) ?? .zero
```

Comment: I tried your code still nil when I enter the first number.

Comment: `numberText` is not optional. It can't be nil. I am using the nil coalescing operator `??` to assign `.zero` in case of an invalid string value.